# DataFormatString for Short ISO-8601 Date in ASP.NET MVC Editor Template

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html, datetime-format

In my ASP.NET MVC5 project, I want to edit `DateTime` types with a `Html.TextBox` that display the date returned from the database in the short date format for local time.  Using HTML5 in the Chrome browser, and `input type="date"` tags, I must use the `value` attribute in the ISO-8601 format.  The only way I could readily figure out how to do this was to use the date format string `"{0:yyyy-MM-dd}"` in my editor template.

Please let me know if hardcoding the date format string to `"{0:yyyy-MM-dd}"` is the only way to display the date, or if there is another way to use the short date format to specify a culture or templated format that adheres to the ISO-8601 date standard. For example, `"{0:d}"` with `CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(something)` somehow.

I know that it is not necessarily recommended to use HTML5 due to the evolving support of `input type=date`, that's not what this question is about.  I also realize that `"{0:yyyy-MM-dd}"` may be a lot easier than using a culture, I am only curious.

My cshtml EditorTemplate for my nullable `DateTime` type:

```
@model DateTime?

@if (Model != null)
{
    @Html.TextBox("", Model, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", new { @type = "date" })  // all datetime's in my preexisting database deal with just the date portion.
}
else
{
    @Html.TextBox("", "", new { @type = "date" })
}
```